# link adapter to a list view in another activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm working on a posting system in an app.
What I want to do is when I press on the post icon I'll go to another `Activity` where I have an `EditText` and a `Button`.
When I press the button I want to get the text from the `EditText` and post it in the `ListView` of the main page or the "feed" page.
I don't seem to know how to link the array adapter to the feed so that the text appears on the `ListView`.

This is the code:

Main where I need to know what to do:

```
package com.example.ali.test1;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity   {

    EditText input;
    ListView list1;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        int id2 = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        } else if (id2 == R.id.action_cart) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Post.class));
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is the post activity :

```
package com.example.ali.test1;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Post extends ActionBarActivity {
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1;
    EditText input;
    ListView list;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

        // android:id="@+id/input"
        input = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);
        // android:id="@+id/list"

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new ArrayList<String>());
    }

    // android:onClick="addToList"
    public void addToList(View view) {
        adapter.add(input.getText().toString());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        // Clear the input
        input.setText("");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_post, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

These are xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.ali.test1.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

post:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.ali.test1.Post">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/list" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add to list"
        android:onClick="addToList"
        android:layout_below="@id/input"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you!

Comment: You want to use interface/listeners or OnActivityResult. From your description I honestly can't tell which one will be easier to implement.

Comment: I need to update the list in main activity by adding the text I write in the post activity in the text field

Comment: Basically my question is how do i get the text written in the edit text of Post actiity and add it in the listview of the main activity

Comment: Allowing `MainActivity` to receive data from `Post` requires it to be opened with `startActivityForResult` method and `MainActivity` to implement  `onActivityResult` (here is where you can update your UI). You can refer to Android documentation [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) for details.

Comment: okay will do thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the method `startActivityForResult(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Post.class),1);` 
in the post activity

```
public void finish (View v){
    String text = input.getText();
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.putExtra("result",text);
    setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK,intent);
    finish();
}
```

and in the main activity you need to define a list for arrayAdapter and add the result to the arrayList

@Override

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            String result=data.getStringExtra("result");
            list.add(result);
             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
      }
}
```

Comment: okay I'm applying what you said hopefully it will work thank you

Comment: where exactly should I add this : startActivityForResult(new Intent(MainActivity.this, Post.class); It says cannot resolve method.

Comment: sorry I forget to  specify the request number I have edited the post take a look

Comment: I did what you said but now it's crashing when the app starts directly

Comment: it's been a while sorry but I noticed that when I use your methods, I'm not getting any result in the listview and if I try and Write list.add it gives me an error @user5506102

Answer (score 0):

If the post activity is opened from the main activity - then the sensible way to do this here is to use "startActivityForResult". Your main activity should start your post activity and receive the result in 
it's all here in the documentation : http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

You can pass the text value from the post activity back to the main activity in the extras bundle passed to onActivityResult.